Horizontal thrust to a dormer
Lateral restraint of walls
I added two dormers to my house to finish the attic area. My house was built in 1923 and the exterior is brick. After my original permit was approved, the inspector required me to pull a second permit to finish the space. My second permit was rejected because I do not account for how the horizontal thrust will be resisted. I have seen some solutions where they put a stainless steel bar from the outside wall and connect to the floor joists. My exterior wall is not easily accessible as the roof sits directly on top of the wall. What are my options here? The dormer is 20 feet long on easy side of the house. I have 5.5 foot side walls.
